# I'm not getting something. String == String False

Tags: android, if-statement, equals-operator

Why is this False? I can't get it. DataBaseHelper.getBoolean(); is a string value. In this if statement it outputs the same result but it says it is not equal with each other..

```
            String a = DataBaseHelper.getBoolean(id);
            String b = DataBaseHelper.getBoolean(id);
            if (a==b){
                newTextView.setText(DataBaseHelper.getBoolean(id) + " == " + DataBaseHelper.getBoolean(id) + " is TRUE \n");
            } else {
                newTextView.setText(DataBaseHelper.getBoolean(id) + " == " + DataBaseHelper.getBoolean(id) + " is FALSE \n");
            }
```

getBoolean method from toher class.

```
public String getBoolean(int randomIndex) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        open();
        Cursor c = myDataBase.query(TABLE_NAME1, columns, WHATTODONOW_COLUMN_ID
                + "=" + randomIndex, null, null, null, null);
        if (c != null) {
            c.moveToFirst();
            String text = c.getString(8);
            return text;
        }
        closee();
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Comparing a string value by using `==` will not work, use `equals()` method.

Comment: Try to search your question first and then ask :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

because String `a` and String `b` objects are different (`==` test for reference equality). you should compare String instance through `equals`

```
if (a.equals(b)) {}
```

Comment: Strange. Actually that is not `address`. This is because of `a` and `b` both are different object.

Comment: It was what I meant. Your definition is more clear, thanks @PankajKumar

Comment: No concept of address in Java. BTW most welcome

Answer (score 1):

You should use `a.equals(b)` or `a.equalsIgnoreCase(b)` instead of `==` operator to compare String. `==` operator compares the references of the two operands. Your `a` and `b` are different String objects hence it fails .

Answer (score 1):

Try with one of following

> if (a.equals(b)) {}

And

> if (a.equalsIgnoreCase(b)) {}